# Why javascript does not return rounded number

Tags: javascript, computer-science, symbolic-math

```

```
function addTwoDigits(n) {
var result;
result = Math.floor(n/10) + 10*(n/10-Math.floor(n/10));
console.log(result);
return result;

}
addTwoDigits(29);
```

```
the output was 10.9999999999999999999999999999999
I wonder why it was not 11 since according to normal way of calculation it should be rounded already but it's not. Is there any hidden computer science thoery behind this?

Comment: check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

put **Math.round()**

```
function addTwoDigits(n) {
var result;
result = Math.floor(n/10) + 10*(n/10-Math.floor(n/10));
console.log(Math.round(result));
return result;

}
addTwoDigits(29);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: tks for sparing your time, but I actually mean was that i wanna know Why the result was 10.99999999. I do know we could use Math.round alreaduy :D